# Remember "local" bash history in a folder?

Tags: bash, directory, command-history

I have a script in a folder that I use with long arguments.
Is there any chance I can have an history of the commands executed in that specific directory instead of going back through the entire history?

Comment: Interesting question. BTW, nstead of going back "through the entire history" you might use Ctrl+R to search it, that's what I would do in such situations.

Comment: yeah, it helps but in this way I only have the last one. Is there any possibility to have more than one result?

Comment: You can keep pressing Ctrl+R once you have entered part of the command name.

Comment: `history | less` perhaps? It doesn't really answer your question but that's where I'd start.

Comment: @roaima And then searching using _"/"_ + _search-term_ + _enter_ and then _"n"/"N"_ for further searching forwards/backwards.

Comment: @phk yes. I assumed knowledge of a pager. Perhaps I was wrong to do so. `G` and then cursor-up/page-up.

Comment: This is a great idea, and very handy, but you may also choose to record your commonly run commands as a local script, a Makefile, or [redo](https://github.com/apenwarr/redo), etc.

Answer (score 5):

By hooking into bash's PROMPT_COMMAND, this function gets run every time you get a new prompt, so it's a decent time to check to see if you are in a directory that you want a custom history for. The function has four main branches:

1. If the current directory (`$PWD`) has not changed, then do nothing (return).

If the PWD *has* changed, then we set up a local function whose only purpose is to factor the "custom directory" code into one place. You'll want to replace my test-directories with your own (separated by `|`).

2. If we have not changed into or out of a custom directory, then simply update  the "previous directory" variable and return out of the function.

Since we've changed directories, update the "previous directory" variable, then save the in-memory history out to the HISTFILE, then clear the in-memory history.

3. If we've changed *into* a custom directory, then set HISTFILE to be a `.bash_history` file in the current directory.
4. Otherwise, we've changed *out of* a custom directory, so reset HISTFILE to the stock one.

Finally, since we've changed history files, read back in that previous history.

To get things going, the script sets the PROMPT_COMMAND value and saves two internal-use variables (the stock HISTFILE and the "previous directory").

```
prompt_command() {
  # if PWD has not changed, just return
  [[ $PWD == $_cust_hist_opwd ]] && return

  function iscustom {
    # returns 'true' if the passed argument is a custom-history directory
    case "$1" in
      ( */tmp/faber/somedir | */tmp/faber/someotherdir ) return 0;;
      ( * ) return 1;;
    esac
  }

  # PWD changed, but it's not to or from a custom-history directory,
  # so update opwd and return
  if ! iscustom "$PWD" && ! iscustom "$_cust_hist_opwd"
  then
    _cust_hist_opwd=$PWD
    return
  fi

  # we've changed directories to and/or from a custom-history directory

  # save the new PWD
  _cust_hist_opwd=$PWD

  # save and then clear the old history
  history -a
  history -c

  # if we've changed into or out of a custom directory, set or reset HISTFILE appropriately
  if iscustom "$PWD"
  then
    HISTFILE=$PWD/.bash_history
  else
    HISTFILE=$_cust_hist_stock_histfile
  fi

  # pull back in the previous history
  history -r
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_command'
_cust_hist_stock_histfile=$HISTFILE
_cust_hist_opwd=$PWD
```

Answer (score 2):

Jeff's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323485/351036) is great if you want the history for a single directory, but if you're OK with installing [zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) you could use [per-history-directory](https://github.com/jimhester/per-directory-history) to get a history specific to the directory for all directories.

You can install zsh by:

```
brew install zsh
```

Alternatively, if you want to install [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), you could add in the [histdb](https://github.com/larkery/zsh-histdb) plugin and write a custom query to query the sqlite db that histdb adds in. I wrote about that and adding auto completions in a [Dev Diaries](https://www.dev-diaries.com/blog/terminal-history-auto-suggestions-as-you-type/) post. Check the [bonus commands](https://www.dev-diaries.com/blog/terminal-history-auto-suggestions-as-you-type/#bonus-commands) section.

The query looks like this

```
show_local_history() {
    limit="${1:-10}"
    local query="
        select history.start_time, commands.argv 
        from history left join commands on history.command_id = commands.rowid
        left join places on history.place_id = places.rowid
        where places.dir LIKE '$(sql_escape $PWD)%'
        order by history.start_time desc
        limit $limit
    "
    results=$(_histdb_query "$query")
    echo "$results"
}
```

This accepts an optional limit as well:

```
show_local_history 50
```

for example.

Comment: Is it possible to have bash look into for the nearest parent folder with a .bash_history if not in current directory and loads it. I don't think I would want a history in each of the folders I visit but it would nice to keep different projects folders with separate histories as the commands are totally different/unrelated. Currently working in one area pollutes the single bash_history file. code appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

When I need to use a command with long arguments several times, I usually create an alias in my `~/.bash_aliases` or you can put it in your `~/.bashrc` if you prefer. It's easy and save time instead look for old commands in history.

Comment: That's a good hint but not what OP was looking for. OP was quite specific for what he/she was looking for (a solution I would sign up as well BTW).

Comment: @phk You're right, I'll be more careful next time! Thanks for your explanation!